# Is there a way to extract certain file from pod directly from its node ? (containerd runtime)

Tags: kubernetes, containers, containerd

We have collected memory dump of one pod and its size is huge. I`m not able to get it using kubectl cp.
Are there any alternatives? Can it be extracted directly from nodes file system?

I have tried to find it on node directly, no luck.

Comment: Since you mentioned, you have access to the node, check with crictl or docker if your pod/container is still there. If yes, you can use the inspect option of the command to get the host path of the container (Look into the section "GraphDriver" if overlay is used).

Comment: @CLNRMN I have checked running pods and inspected them, I have found out volume path, but unfortunately was not able to extract anything from that because it contains: vold_data.json file and empty mount folder.

Comment: Can you set the folder for the memory dump? E.g. -XX:HeapDumpPath=/dumpfolder for Java?

Comment: I think you have to provide more information, e.q. the Pod spec and where the file was placed.